# What gauge field can be constructed from Lorentz symmetry?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gauge-theory, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

You can take a global symmetry and promote it to a local gauge symmetry by introducing an appropriate gauge field and upgrading the partial derivative to a covariant derivative. The photon field arises from global $U(1)$ symmetry, the gluon field from $SU(3)$ and even gravity shows up this way (though it's more elaborate since the symmetry group of general coordinate transformations is infinite and compact, differently from your usual $SU(N)$).

What gauge field do I get from Lorentz symmetry?

Comment: Since the obvious answer is "A $\mathrm{SO}(1,3)$ gauge field", could you make more precise what you mean with this question?

Comment: Yes, but what physical, measurable particle corresponds to the $SO(1,3)$ gauge field? We have photon for $U(1)$, gluon for $SU(3)$, etc.

Comment: None. The Standard model does *not* have the Lorentz group as a gauge group.

Comment: See well-ansered [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108523/the-spin-connection).

Answer (score 6):

It is the celebrated [spin connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection) on the tangent space, gauging Lorentz rotations so you can take Lorentz covariant derivatives on spinors---you would not be able to do Supergravity without it.

As you see, however, $\omega_\mu^{ab}$ is a composite gauge field, that is, it is is an elaborate function of Vierbeine (or Vielbeine) and their derivatives, ensuring tangent space Lorentz invariance, and not a fundamental field. No matter, it is necessary, and GR fermions live by it!

You might enjoy [this review](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.36.463).