# Verifying infinitesimal form of 2.4.26 from Polchinski

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

According to equation 2.4.26 of Polchinski's String Theory Volume 1, the finite transformation of the energy momentum tensor is

$$ (\partial z')^2 T'(z') = T(z) - \frac{c}{12} \{z',z\}\tag{2.4.26}$$

Where $$\{z',z\} = \frac{2 \partial^3 z' \partial z' - 3 \partial^2 z' \partial^2 z' }{2 \partial z' \partial z'}. \tag{2.4.27}$$

From here I need to show that the infinitesimal form of the transformation  equation 2.4.24

$$\epsilon^{-1} \delta T(z) = -\frac{c}{12 } \partial^3 v(z)  - 2 \partial v(z) T(z) - v(z) \partial T(z).\tag{2.4.24} $$

How do I go about this? I tried to start by assuming that $$ z' = z + \epsilon v(z)$$

Then I ignored terms in $\epsilon$ and and higher powers of $\epsilon$. This is my first encounter with CFT and so am unsure if this is the right way to do it.

EDIT: Here is my work.

$$ \Big(\frac{\partial z'}{\partial z}\Big)^2 = (1 + \epsilon v')^2$$

The Schwarzian derivative is:

$$ \{z',z\} = \frac{2 \epsilon v'''(z) (1 + \epsilon v'(z)) - 3 \epsilon^2 v'(z)^2}{2(1 + \epsilon v'(z))^2}.$$

I multiplied both sides of the equation by $2 (1 + \epsilon v'(z))^2$ and ended up with, up to terms of leading order in $\epsilon$

$$ 2(1 + 4 \epsilon v'(z)) T'(z') = 2(1+ 2 \epsilon v'(z)) T(z) - \frac{c}{12} (2 \epsilon v'''(z)).$$

Divide both sides by $2 \epsilon$:

$$ \epsilon^{-1} (T'(z') - T(z)) = -\frac{c}{12} \partial^3 v(z) + 2 \partial v(z) T(z) - 4 \partial v(z) T'(z').$$

Thus, we have

$$  \epsilon^{-1} \delta T (z) = -\frac{c}{12} \partial^3 v(z) - 2 \partial v(z) T(z) + 4 \partial v(z) T(z) - 4 \partial v(z) T'(z').$$

In particular, I am unsure if the following is true:

$$ \delta T(z) = T'(z') - T(z) .$$

I am also unsure about how to bring about the $2 \partial v(z) T(z)$ term.

How do I proceed?

Comment: You need calculate in linear order in $\epsilon$.

Comment: delta T(z) is T’(z)-T(z), so you need to Taylor expand T’(z’)

Comment: @Wakabaloola Right, the difference is between the two functions evaluated at the same point. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483612/2451 and links therein.