# Central charge in energy-momentum tensor OPE

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wick-theorem

I think that general point of view  about central charge in books is considering OPE $T(z) T(w)$ for different field theories and finding that general expression for the most singular term is about to be $\sim \frac{c/2}{(z-w)^4}$. Then we do operator expansion $$T(z) = \sum \frac{L_n}{z^{n+2}}$$ and see that operators $L_n$ form Virasoro algebra.
Or we can write transformation law for $T(z)$ and see that generally it's not a tensor, and here central charge comes into play again.

**My question:** I wonder if there is any way to start from Virasoro algebra generators and to prove that energy-momentum tensor in arbitrary theory must contain the term $\frac{c/2}{(z-w)^4}$ in its OPE with itself, where $c$ is a central charge of Virasoro algebra?

Another way to show this is to prove that operator expansion of $T(z)$ is always $\sum \frac{L_n}{z^{n+2}}$, where $L_n$ are Virasoro generators.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question here is. By *definition of quantization*, a central charge appears when we quantize the Witt algebra, cf. [this Q&A of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/50583), and then the central charge has to appear in the expansion of $T(z) = L_n z^{-n-2}$ since it is in the commutation relation of $L_n$ of equal level, and the $-2$ already shows this charge will thus play its role at $(z-w)^{-4}$. Are you asking why the central charge appears, or why the e-m tensor is $\sum_n L_n z^{-n-2}$?

Comment: Well, I think, both))

Answer (score 2):

1. The central charge itself appears in the commutation relations because the quantum theory allows not only linear, but *projective* representations of the conformal Witt algebra to be physically admissible. Such projective representations are in bijection to linear representations of the central extensions of the Witt algebra
   $$[L_m,L_n] = (m-n)L_{m+n}$$
   which are the Virasoro algebras
   $$ [L_m,L_n] = (m-n)L_{m+n} + \frac{c}{12}(m^3-m)\delta_{m,-n} $$
   for $c\in\mathbb{R}$. For more on projective representations and central extensions, see [this Q&A of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/50583).
2. The energy-momentum tensor classically has conformal weight $2$, so its conformal mode expansion is $T(z) = \sum_n T_n z^{-n+2}$. The question now becomes how one shows that $T_n = L_n$. Since the energy-momentum tensor is the conserved current for the translations generated by $L_{-1} = \partial_z$ (since $L_n = z^{-n+1}\partial_z$), its integral has to be the generator $L_{-1}$ itself (the integral of the conserved current is the Noether charge, which is the generator of the symmetry in the Hamiltonian formulations):
   $$ L_{-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int T(z)\mathrm{d}z$$
   and inserting the mode expansion we get $L_{-1} = T_{-1}$. More generally, for any conformal transformation $z\mapsto z+\epsilon(z)$, we get a conserved current $\epsilon(z)T(z)$. The $L_n$ generate the transformations $z\mapsto z + \epsilon_n z^{n+1}$. As above, it follows that
   $$ L_n = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int z^{n+1}T(z)\mathrm{d}z$$
   and thus $L_n = T_n$. Therefore, the energy-momentum tensor of a conformal field theory is $T(z) = \sum_z L_n z^{-n+2}$.

<sub>Here we only considered the holomorphic parts, but the arguments for the anti-holomorphic pieces are exacctly the same</sub>

Comment: How do you prove that, if $T(z)=\sum_n L_n z^{-n-2}$ then $T(y)T(z)=c/2(y-z)^{-4}+2T(z)(y-z)^{-2}+\partial T(z)(y-z)^{-1}+O(1)$? I guess the second and third term follow by $L_{-1}T(z)=\partial T(z)$ by def. of the $L_{-1}$ action and $L_0 T(z)=2T(z)$ by the conformal dimension of $T$. Furthermore, the triple pole can be excluded by symmetry reasons. But what about the first term? How do I see that $L_{-2}T=c/2$?

Answer (score 0):

$T(z)$ has dimension 2. Thus, the OPE $T(z)T(0)$ has dimension 4. This implies that the most singular piece in this OPE that can possibly appear is $z^{-4}$. The operator that multiplies this singularity has dimension $0$. In a unitary CFT, the only such operator is the identity operator. Thus, the coefficient of $z^{-4}$ can only be a $c$-number. Further since this is appearing in the $TT$ OPE it must be real and positive (again due to unitarity).

Thus the most singular piece must take the form
$$
T(z)T(0) \sim \frac{c}{2z^4} + \cdots
$$

This doesn't say that this term must exist, since we could easily have $c=0$. However, you can derive the Virasoro algebra with $c=0$ (also called the Witt algebra) and ask what kind of representations can occur in a unitary theory. It is easily shown that with $c=0$, only a identity module can occur in the quantum theory which makes the theory trivial.

Thus, in non-trivial unitary quantum field theories, you *must* have $c > 0$.