# Are there finite-dimensional unitary irreducible representations in Euclidean space?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, unitarity

One can show that [there are no unitary finite-dimensional irreducible representations of the Poincaré group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293539/can-the-finite-dimensional-irreducible-j-j-representations-of-the-lorent). The reason is that the generators for boosts are antihermitian.

Since boosts are basically time-space rotations, this led to me wondering whether for Euclidean space, where we don't have minus signs in the metric, we can have finite-dimensional unitary irreps like we can for space-space (read: usual) rotations?

Comment: You should probably add "no finite dimensional unitary". Otherwise, this statement is wrong (as one can see at the post.

Comment: Oh sure, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there are none (apart from the trivial rep.). This follows not because of the metric but because the transformations on Euclidean space still form a non-compact group, like Poincaré.

The best you can do apparently is to have indecomposable representations, and that’s a mess because that representation theory is “wild”.  The case of $E(2)$ is somewhat tractable and discussed at some length in

> Repka, J. and de Guise, H., 1999. Some finite dimensional indecomposable representations of E (2). Journal of Mathematical Physics, 40(11), pp.6087-6109

(available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/J_Repka/publication/234997228_Some_finite_dimensional_indecomposable_representations_of_E2/links/56f95d4908ae81582bf4384d.pdf)) and follow up papers mostly by A. Douglas.

Recall that (roughly speaking) fully reducible representations can be brought to full block diagonal form:
$$
T\to \left(\begin{array}{cc} T_1 &\boldsymbol{0}\\ \boldsymbol{0} &T_2
\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
Indecomposables can only be made partially block diagonal:
$$
A\to \left(\begin{array}{cc} A_1 &A_{12}\\ \boldsymbol{0} &A_2
\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
For irreducibles one cannot make a $\boldsymbol{0}$ block appear anywhere.

In fact, the "natural" representation of the Euclidean group $E(n)$ is precisely by a indecomposable matrix:
\begin{align}
T\to \left(\begin{array}{cc}
R&t\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
where $R\in O(n)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $t$ is a column vector
of $n$ entries giving the translation part of the group action.