# Projective representations and understanding "non-trivial" two-cocycles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-representations, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

A symmetry group $\mathcal{G}$ may be represented on the physical Hilbert space by unitary operators $U(g)$ such that it satisfies the composition rule $$U(g_1)U(g_2)=e^{i\phi(g_1,g_2)}U(g_1g_2).\tag{1}$$ If $\phi(g_1,g_2)$ is of the form $$\phi(g_1,g_2)=\alpha(g_1g_2)-\alpha(g_1)-\alpha(g_2)\tag{2}$$ the projective representations in (1) with such a phase (2) can be replaced by an ordinary representation by replacing $U(g)$ with $$\tilde{U}(g)=e^{i\alpha(g)}U(g).\tag{3}$$ If I understand it correct, Weinberg says in his QFT book that $\phi=0$ satisfies relation (2), and is therefore, a trivial two-cocycle. I don't understand why $\phi=\pi$ cannot satisfy the relation (2). It is satisfied by choosing $$\pi+\alpha(g_1g_2)=\alpha(g_1)+\alpha(g_2)\tag{4}.$$

Therefore, projective representations corresponding to $\phi=\pi$ (or any constant value of $\phi$), can be eliminated by defining a new representation of the form (3). Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch (4) is not from Weinberg. My question is why $\phi=0$ is said to satisfy (2) but not some other value of $\phi$ (say, $\phi=\pi$)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Can you explain in what sense $\phi=0$ satisfies (2)? I think the way I'm understanding it may not be correct. And I edited the question and hope it is less confusing now?

Comment: You say *"I don't understand why ϕ=π cannot satisfy the relation (2)."*  But $\phi=\pi$ *can* satisfy (2) -- I gave you an example.  Is this really your question? IMO, the question I would find interesting would be "is *any* proj. representation with $\phi=\pi$ of the form (2)".  Can you clarify this?  ---  Regarding my other comment: For $\phi=0$, just choose $\alpha(g)\equiv 0$. Then, (2) holds.

Comment: Ok, it is indeed (quite trivially) generally true. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: Any projective representation $U(g)$ with $\phi(g_1,g_2)=\pi$ can be made a linear representation by replacing
$$
\tilde U(g) = -U(g)\ .
$$
This corresponds to choosing $\alpha(g)=\pi$ in Eq. (2).  (Note that while this satisfies (4), it is not clear whether Eq. (4) itself is a good definition -- it is not clear that $\alpha(g)$ for each $g$ is uniquely defined this way.)

Indeed, this is generally true when $\phi(g_1,g_2)=\vartheta$ is constant: In each of these cases, you can define $\tilde U(g)=e^{-i\vartheta}U(g)$, or $\alpha(g)=-\vartheta$.

Comment: Dear @Norbert Schuch This is what I understand from your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong. A phase $\phi(g_1,g_2)$ which does not satisfy (2) cannot be a mere constant because all constant $\phi$ can be made to satisfy (2). Is that correct? Therefore, does it not mean that all projective representations with constant $\phi$,  can be replaced by ordinary representation? And for non-trivial projective representation, one must have a phase $\phi(g_1,g_2)$ which is different from a constant?

Comment: Precisely.   $\quad$

Answer (score 1):

No one makes any claim that it *doesn't* work for $\phi = \pi$ as well! The whole point of the relation between projective and linear representation is that a single projective representation can have *more* than one pair of $(U,\phi)$ related to it.

I discuss the relation between projective representations and unitary representations at length in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203945/50583). The relevant point to your question is the *coboundary condition*: Two functions $\phi(g_1,g_2)$ and $\phi'(g_1,g_2)$ define the same projective representation if there exists another function $\alpha(g)$ such that
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\phi'(g_1,g_2)}\mathrm{e}^{\alpha(g_1g_2)} = \mathrm{e}^{\alpha(g_1)}\mathrm{e}^{\alpha(g_2)}\mathrm{e}^{\phi(g_1,g_2)},$$
which is eq. (2) from my other answer written in your exponential notation. Your eq. (2) is exactly this for $\phi' = 0$, meaning the statement looks kind of vacuous from this viewpoint: Of course $\phi=0$ and $\phi'=0$ define the same representation!

You are correct that this works for *any* constant functions $\phi,\phi'$, they all belong to the same projective representation. This is kind of the point of the whole construction: When you *choose* a pair $(U,\phi)$ to turn a projective representation into a "twisted" linear representation on the original Hilbert space, this choice is *not unique* and two choices ("cocycles") fulfilling certain relations with each other (the "coboundary" conditions) always come from the same projective representation. For more detail, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Projective representations aren’t faithful by their very construction. If this was a ‘normal’ faithful representation (to the same target space), you’d have a group homomorphism, i.e. no phase factor.