# Needs of unitary representation for QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hilbert-space, unitarity, poincare-symmetry

Weinberg book states the following (pg. 231):

> "There is no problem in working with non-unitary representations, because the objects we are now concerned with are fields, not wave functions, and do not need to have a Lorentz-invariant positive norm"

Schwartz book states the following (pg. 110 and 165)

> "In addition we want unitary representation...."

> "To construct a unitary filed theory we need unitary representation..."

So my question is: is it strictly needed to have unitary representation of the Poincare' group? If it's so, what is the underlying reason?

Comment: The infinite dimensional Hilbert space of states must carry a unitary representation of the Poincaré group (or rather its universal cover). On the other hand the finite dimensional vector space on which fields takes values does not. In fact, it can't, because non-compact groups (like Poincaré) do not have finite dimensional unitary representations.

Comment: @Gold sorry to nitpick, but you're surely familiar with unitary representations of $\mathbb{R}$ :) (What you want is true for semisimple groups, and of course Poincaré contains a semisimple Lorentz group.)

Answer (score 4):

In order to understand what kind of representations you need, you have to look at a fundamental theorem about symmetries in quantum physics: Wigner's theorem.

A Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ is technically not the space of pure states, as there is a redundancy. Two vectors related by a complex number
$$ \psi' = \lambda\psi, \qquad \lambda\in\mathbb C$$
describe the same state. Or if you work with normalized states, then $\lambda = e^{i\theta}$. Therefore, you need to identify $\psi'\sim \psi$ all such vectors and what you get is a **ray**
$$ [\psi] = \{\psi'\in S\mathcal H \, \big| \, \exists e^{i\theta}\in U(1), \text{ s.t. } \psi' = e^{i\theta}\psi\}. $$
Here by $S\mathcal H$ I mean the submanifold of unit vectors (sphere in $\mathcal H$).
Alternatively, a pure state can be described by a density matrix
$$ \rho_\psi = \frac{|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}.$$
The space of such rays is a projective space $\mathbb P\mathcal H$, and thus not linear. Now, on this space you can define the transition probability between two different states (rays), which is nothing but the Born rule
$$ P\left([\psi]\rightarrow [\phi]\right) = |\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2 = tr(\rho_\psi\rho_\phi).$$
A symmetry can now be defined as a bijection on the space of physical states $\mathbb P\mathcal H\rightarrow \mathbb P\mathcal H$ that preserves the transition probabilities. The set of such symmetries forms a group $G$.

However, we prefer to work with the (linear) Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ than the space of rays $\mathbb P\mathcal H$. The question is now, how should such symmetries be represented on the Hilbert space when lifted up from $\mathbb P\mathcal H$?

Wigner's theorem states that symmetries must be represented as projective unitary or anti-unitary representations on $\mathcal H$.

The projective part is why we have to allow spinor representations (fermions), for example why we work with $Spin(3)=SU(2)$ (universal cover of SO(3)) when we really have $SO(3)$ symmetry. Or with $\mathbb R^4\rtimes Spin(1,3)=\mathbb R^4\rtimes SL(2,\mathbb C)$ when we have Poincare symmetry $\mathbb P = \mathbb R^4\rtimes SO(1,3)$.

Anti-unitary representations only really show up when considering time-reversal symmetry and it's usually a combination of complex conjugation and regular unitary representation.

For topologically compact Lie groups like $SO(3)$, we have finite dimensional unitary representations. For example we can decompose the infinite dimensional space of square integrable functions on the sphere
$$L^2(S^2) = \{\,\psi:S^2\rightarrow\mathbb C,\,\big| \, \int d\theta d\phi\,|\psi(\theta,\phi)|^2<\infty\,\} $$
into infititely many finite-dimensional spaces
$$ L^2(S^2) = \bigoplus_{s=0}^\infty \mathcal H_s,$$
where each space $\mathcal H_s$ corresponds to the irreducible spin-$s$ representation and spanned by Spherical Harmonic functions.

For topologically non-compact groups like the Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$, all unitary representation are infinite dimensional. There are finite dimensional representations, but they are not unitary (or anti-unitary).

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of represenation of lorentz group.

One is unitary, the representation space is particle space, labeled by 4 momentum and spins, and calculated by induced representation theory.

The other is the representation theory of fields, which is not unitary.

Weinberg uses particles to builds fields. Schwartz calls it embedding particle into fields.