# What is the difference between a ''unitary representation'' and a ''projective unitary representation''?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, representation-theory

It is assumed that a valid QFT, must have states/observables in a Hilbert space, transform according to the **projective unitary representations** of the Poincare group.

I can understand why the observables must transform according to unitary representations of the Poincare group, but don't see any compelling reason for that symmetries must be projective as well.

[Some](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675174/needs-of-unitary-representation-for-qft#:%7E:text=Wigner%27s%20theorem%20states%20that%20symmetries,SO(3)%20symmetry.) have explained it, as it is required for dealing with the phase factor redundancy in the wavefunction,but I guess this redundancy is dealt by the unitary representation itself, as the phase factors cancels out. I don't see why a phase factor redundancy demands the symmetry be projective.

Comment: What do you mean "the phase factors cancels out"? The prime example of a projective but not unitary representation is the spin-1/2 representation of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$. Are you trying to argue there should be no half-spin objects in QM? See also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203945/50583) for the relation between projective representations and unitary representations of larger groups

Comment: when we have a state, $\psi$ and another $e^{i\theta}\psi$, they are related by a phase factor $e^{i\theta}$, and when we calculate the probabilities, these phase factors gets cancels out.

this is what I mean. 

Regarding the spin -1/2, I am not. I just want to make my conceptions clear.

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific what bothers you here - the usual arguments for why we need projective and not just unitary representation are precisely *because* that phase factor cancels out of the Born rule so the elements of the representation can fulfill the more "relaxed" group composition rule $\Sigma(g)\Sigma(h) = C(g,h)\Sigma(gh)$ (notation see my linked answer) instead of the usual $U(g)U(h) = U(gh)$ for a strictly unitary representation.

Comment: A projective representation of an algebra (e.g., group) reproduces the algebra up to a complex phase, as you noted. Demanding a projective representation is less stringent of a requirement than demanding an ordinary one. As mentioned above, this can be done to allow the use of *universal covering groups*, like SU(2) for SO(3), where the half-odd-integer irreps of SU(2) are projective irreps of SO(3), while the integer irreps of SU(2) are ordinary irreps of SO(3). I don't have an physical explanation for why this *should* be so. I imagine it's an observation, and not *a priori* justified.

Comment: I was thinking of the term "projective" from the projective geomtry point of view, in which case, the main feature is of the inversion of the orientation as illustrated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane). While I think it is used just as a projection map in the sense of a fibre. May be I am illegally mixing ideas from manifolds and groups