# Why we need $SU(2)$ symmetry? When we use it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am trying to learn Quantum mechanics and I am familiar with Pauli matrice but not with group theory. I want to understand SU2 symmetry in common language. When we talk about Pauli matrix x we simply say that it flips the spin. What SU2 symmetry does?What is the advantage of using SU2 symmetry? Can someone please explain this in simple language?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Queries about rotational groups $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ in QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329413/84967).

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* herry!  I've down-voted your question for the reason that it is unclear.  I've also voted to close your question for the reason that it is unclear what you're asking.  *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight excactly what you need.  As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  See the [How to Ask page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Queries about rotational groups $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ in QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329413/queries-about-rotational-groups-mathrmso3-and-mathrmsu2-in-qm)

Answer (score 1):

The Pauli matrices turn up in a number of places. They're basically the Lie algebra of SO(3), the 3d rotation group. They're useful in QM to describe spin.

$SU(2)$ is isomorphic to $Spin(3)$ which is the double cover of $SO(2)$. This is helpful in describing 2-component spinors.

You might find it worthwhile working through Shankars book QM as he approaches the subject in a fairly straight-forward and transparent way.