# Homotopy group for spin-1 BEC

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, topological-insulators, topological-phase, soft-matter, topological-defects

Homotopy group can be used to classify topological defects. The procedure is

1. Find the Lie group $G$ that leaves the free-energy functional invariant when transforming $\psi$, where $\psi$ is the quantum state.
2. Find the isotropy group $H$ that leaves $\psi$ invariant.
3. The order parameter manifold is defined as $M =G/H$.
4. Find the homotopy group of $M$: $\pi_n(M)$, which classifies the topological defects.

For spin-1 BEC, the literatures say that $G = SO(3)\times U(1)$ where $SO(3)$ is related to the rotational symmetry in spin space and $U(1)$ is related to the global phase symmetry. Besides $H =U(1)$, hence the order parameter manifold $M = SO(3)$, and the homotopy group is $\pi_n(SO(3))$.

**However, my question is that why the rotational symmetry is expressed as $SO(3)$ instead of $SU(2)$.** In quantum mechanics we usually use the representation of $SU(2)$ to represent a rotation of a quantum state. Although in spin-1 case, it furnishes a representation of $SO(3)$, it also furnishes a representation of $SU(2)$.
If we choose $G=SU(2)\times U(1)$, then the homotopy group would be $\pi_n(SU(2))$, which is different to $\pi_n(SO(3))$ when $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is that why the rotational symmetry is expressed as $SO(3)$
> instead of $SU(2)$

In this case the *rotation* is in the 3D space defined by the three substates of the spin-$1$ system: $m = -1, 0, 1$. If there is a symmetry among these substates, which you are trying to classify, it means that the system is invariant under rotations in sub-spin space. In the same way as the length of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ does not depend on its orientation in the $xyz$ plane, so a particular operator/observable will not depend on the orientation of the *net* spin of the atoms in the $m_x m_y m_z$ space.

Since you have three states, the natural basis to use is something like $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and hence a rotation among them is described by a $3 \times 3$ matrix, hence why $SO(3)$.

$SU(2)$ arises naturally for rotations of spin-$1/2$ systems, where $m = \pm 1/2$ and so you naturally need a $2\times 2$ matrix. The relation between $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ is however much stronger than this, see for example [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329565), but not always trivial. Mainly, $SU(2)$ is the *double-cover* of $SO(3)$, so while you can usually "go from $SU(2)$ to $SO(3)$", the opposite is not always true.

So no, you cannot use the two groups interchangeably. Casing point, the fundamental (first homotopy) group of $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ are different: $$ \pi_1(SO(3)) = \mathbb{Z}_2, \quad \pi_1(SU(2)) = 0,$$
and the first result has profound consequences on the possible permutations of particles in 3D space, that is only two topologically distinct ways are allowed (bosons and fermions).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Although in spin-1 case, it furnishes a representation of $SO(3)$, it also furnishes a representation of $SU(2)$. Since we use $SU(2)$ to represent the action of rotation no matter what angular momentum of spin is, so I think it's more natural to use $SU(2)$.