# Gaining intuition over central extension of algebras

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, lie-algebra

Conformal algebra in 2 dimensions admits a central extension and while the procedure itself is explained in many textbooks quite well, I haven't found a source in which it is reasoned as to why we should carry out the central extension.

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_extension) Wikipedia article, it is stated that the symmetry group of a quantized system usually is a central extension of the classical symmetry group, and in the same way the corresponding symmetry Lie algebra of the quantum system is, in general, a central extension of the classical symmetry algebra.

Can someone please elaborate on this and explain why this is the case?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Oops, sorry that I missed the already existing question on the same. Should I delete this question?

Comment: You decide. It could serve as a bookmark for others with the same question.