# Why should a projective representation of a classical symmetry lift to a non-projective representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-anomalies

**Background**

Take a classical system with symmetry $G$. Suppose we can quantize this to a quantum system with Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The state space of the quantum system is given by the projective Hilbert space $\mathbb{P} \mathcal{H}$. A quantization of the symmetry $G$ (if it exists) is a projective representation $\rho: G \rightarrow U \left( \mathbb{P} \mathcal{H} \right)$ into the unitary operators on $\mathbb{P} \mathcal{H}$.

**Question**

From what I have read, it seems like we want (or physically expect?) this $\rho: G \rightarrow U \left( \mathbb{P} \mathcal{H} \right)$ to lift to a representation $\hat{\rho}: G \rightarrow U \left( \mathcal{H} \right)$. Why is this?

**Motivation**

I am trying to understand why, in certain circumstances, we quantize the central extension of $G$, rather than $G$ itself. For instance in CFT, the symmetry group $G = \text{Conf} \left( \mathbb{R}^{1, 1} \right)$ quantizes to a group whose Lie algebra is the Witt algebra. However in this situation we quantize the central extension of $G$ to arrive at the Virasoro algebra instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A quantization of the symmetry $G$ (if it exists) is a projective representation $\rho:G\rightarrow U(\mathbb P\mathcal H)$ into the unitary operators on $\mathbb P\mathcal H$.

To clarify - $\mathbb P\mathcal H$ is not a vector space, and so I'm not so sure what  a unitary operator on $\mathbb P\mathcal H$ would be.  My assumption is that you are referring to the ray product $(\Phi,\Psi)$ between elements of $\mathbb P\mathcal H$, defined via
$$(\Phi,\Psi):= \frac{|\langle\phi,\psi\rangle|}{\Vert\phi\Vert \ \Vert\psi\Vert}$$
where $\phi,\psi\in \mathcal H$ are any two representatives of the equivalence classes $\Phi$ and $\Psi$.  A symmetry transformation is then a map $T:\mathbb P\mathcal H \rightarrow \mathbb P\mathcal H$ such that $(T\Phi,T\Psi)=(\Phi,\Psi)$. This looks rather like the definition of a unitary operator on a Hilbert space, but there is no notion of linearity present here.

[Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) tells us that any such $T$ can be induced by some unitary or antiunitary operator on $\mathcal H$, which descends to a transformation on $\mathbb P\mathcal H$ in the obvious way. By extension, if we want to represent the action of a symmetry *group* $G$ rather than just a single transformation, we might seek linear representations $\rho:G\rightarrow U(\mathcal H)$. However, requiring $\rho$ to be a true group homomorphism is generally too strong; if it is a homomorphism *up to a phase* - i.e. $\rho(g)\rho(h)=\rho(gh)C(g,h)$ for some phase factor $C(g,h)$ - then it also induces a well-defined group action on $\mathbb P\mathcal H$ because the extra phase factor is lost during the projectivization from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathbb P\mathcal H$.

The takeaway is that the action of a symmetry group $G$ on $\mathbb P\mathcal H$ can be understood through a projective unitary representation of $G$ on $\mathcal H$, so we need to understand the latter if we want to understand how to implement symmetry groups in our theories.

> From what I have read, it seems like we want (or physically expect?) this $\rho$ to lift to a representation $\hat{\rho}: G \rightarrow U \left( \mathcal{H} \right)$

If $\rho:G\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb P\mathcal H)$ is a group action whose elements are symmetry transformations as defined above, then Wigner's theorem tells us that that it lifts to a projective unitary representation $\hat \rho:G\rightarrow \mathbb PU(\mathcal H)$.  It *may* lift to a *genuine* representation - i.e. one might be able to arrange that the phase factors $C(g,h)$ referenced above are all equal to $1$ - but in general this cannot be done.

> I am trying to understand why, in certain circumstances, we quantize the central extension of $G$, rather than $G$ itself.

As it turns out, projective representations of $G$ can be put into one-to-one correspondence with (genuine) linear representations of its central extensions (the same is true for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$).  Since linear representations are far nicer to work with, this is what we tend to study.

ACuriousMind has written a wonderful answer on this subject which you can find [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203944/why-exactly-do-sometimes-universal-covers-and-sometimes-central-extensions-feat?rq=1). I doubt any summary I could provide would do it justice, so I suggest reading it directly if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thanks @J. Murray. This explains why I couldn't find any explanation of why $\rho$ should lift in general. I know that if every projective rep of $G$ doesn't necessarily lift to a genuine rep, we can instead quantize the central extension $\tilde{G}$ of $G$ to resolve this annoyance. So is moving from a theory with symmetry $G$ to $\tilde{G}$ simply a case of convenience? Are there no other motivating reasons?

Comment: @leob Quantum theories reside in the superposition principle which we cannot attain on projective space. We are forced to seek representations on linear (topological) spaces, thus we need Bargmann's-Mackey theory of lifting.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I understand. The projective space $\mathbb{P} \mathcal{H}$ only gives us pure states of the quantum system. A projective unitary representation $\hat{\rho}: G \rightarrow U \left( \mathbb{P} \mathcal{H} \right)$ describes a symmetry of these pure states. However because we can have arbitrary superpositions of pure states, this symmetry must ALWAYS lift to a unitary representation $\rho: G \rightarrow U \left( \mathcal{H} \right)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @leob I think I misunderstood some aspects of your question upon first reading it, so I've reworked my answer. Let me know if the edit does not address your question.

Comment: @J. Murray Great, thank you!