# Questions on Peter Woit's Proof of the Clebsch-Gordan Decomposition Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading Peter Woit's book *Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations*, section 9.42 (a similar version can be found [here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/QM/fall-course.pdf)). In the book he proved a version of the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition theorem for $G=SU(2)$:

> **Theorem 9.1.** The tensor product $(\Pi_{V^{n_1}\otimes V^{n_2}},V^{n_1}\otimes V^{n_2})$ decomposes into irreducible representations as
> $$(\Pi_{n_1+n_2},V^{n_1+n_2})\oplus (\Pi_{n_1+n_2-2},V^{n_1+n_2-2})\oplus\cdots\oplus (\Pi_{|n_1-n_2|},V^{|n_1-n_2|}).$$
> Here, $(\Pi_k,V^k)$ is the $k+1$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2).$

And his proof of this theorem goes roughly like this (this can be found in section 9.4.2):

> proof: The group $U(1)=\{e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{C}:0\leq \theta<2\pi\}$ can be embedded naturally into $SU(2)$ by sending $e^{i\theta}$ to the matrix
> $
> \begin{pmatrix}
> e^{i\theta} & 0\\
> 0& e^{-i\theta}
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $
> And it can be shown that the action of $\Pi_n$ on $U(1)\subset SU(2)$ is given by
> $$
> \Pi_n\begin{pmatrix}
> e^{i\theta} & 0\\
> 0& e^{-i\theta}
> \end{pmatrix}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> e^{in\theta}&&&\\
> & e^{i(n-2)\theta}&&\\
> &&\ddots&&\\
> &&& e^{i(-n+2)\theta}\\
> &&&& e^{i(-n)\theta}
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
> Hence one can show that the character function on this element is given by
> $$
> \chi_{V^n}\begin{pmatrix}
> e^{i\theta} & 0\\
> 0& e^{-i\theta}
> \end{pmatrix}=e^{in\theta}+e^{i(n-2)\theta}+\cdots+e^{-in\theta}=
> \frac{e^{i(n+1) \theta}-e^{-i(n+1) \theta}}{e^{i \theta}-e^{-i \theta}}=\frac{\sin ~(n+1) \theta}{\sin \theta}
> $$
> using the Weyl character formula. Now since the character on a tensor product is multiplicative, one can show that on the group $U(1)$, we have
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \chi_{V^{n_1}\otimes V^{n_2}}&=\chi_{V^{n_1}}\chi_{V^{n_2}}\\
> &=(e^{in_1\theta}+e^{i(n_1-2)\theta}+\cdots+e^{-in_1\theta})\frac{e^{i(n_2+1) \theta}-e^{-i(n_2+1) \theta}}{e^{i \theta}-e^{-i \theta}}\\
> &=\frac{(e^{i(n_1+n_2+1)\theta}-e^{-i(n_1+n_2+1)\theta})+\cdots+(e^{i(n_2-n_1+1)\theta}-e^{-i(n_2-n_1+1)\theta})}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}\\
> &=\chi_{V^{n_1+n_2}}+\chi_{V^{n_1+n_2-2}}+\cdots +\chi_{V^{n_2-n_1}}
> \end{align*}
> $$
> where we are assuming $n_2>n_1$.* So, when we decompose the tensor product of irreducibles into a direct sum of irreducibles, the ones that must occur are exactly those of Theorem 9.1.*

Remarks: Thanks to Meng Cheng's answer, I now see that since every element of $SU(2)$ is a conjugate of some element in $U(1)$, and since the character is a class function, it suffices to consider $\chi|_{U(1)}.$ Then using the fact that $SU(2)$ is compact, hence completely reducible, two representations of $SU(2)$ are equivalent iff they have the same character. This completes the proof.
(Although I am not entirely sure how to write $S\in SU(2)$ as $QUQ^{-1}$ for some $Q\in SU(2), U\in U(1)$. I will appreciate it if somebody can explain it to me).

**My Question:**

I know that the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition theorem has something to do with the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and the addition of angular momentum. But from this purely abstract treatment, I cannot see how they are related. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: For Q 1, characters are functions of conjugacy classes, and for SU(2) up to conjugacy every element is in a U(1) subgroup. So it's enough to consider U(1). For 2, it's a standard result in finite-dimensional representations of (finite or compact) groups.

Comment: To reopen this post (v1) consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: Woit as in most pure math treatments of the question only care about the abstract decomposition, whereas physicists require a decomposition with explicit intertwiners, i.e., as in ACuriousMind's answer one needs to explain precisely what $| J_im_{J_i}\rangle$ means as a vector inside $V_{j_1}\otimes V_{j_2}$. You can find more info in my MO answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439481/clebsch-gordan-decomposition-formula-for-algebraic-groups?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In the decomposition
$$ V_{j_1}\otimes V_{j_2} = \oplus_i V_{J_i}$$
you have on the one hand the natural basis $\lvert j_1m_1j_2m_2\rangle = \lvert j_1m_1\rangle \otimes \lvert j_2m_2\rangle$ of the tensor product and on the other hand the natural bases $\lvert J_i m_{J_i}\rangle$ of each of the summands on the r.h.s.

The Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are the inner products $\langle j_1m_1j_2m_2\vert J_i m_{J_i}\rangle$ between these two bases (defined to be zero when $J_i$ does not occur on the r.h.s. at all).

Comment: Thanks!  But in the case of angular momentum, is the group still SU(2)? Or is it SO(3) instead?

Comment: @TianyiWang That...probably doesn't matter as much as you think, since we usually look at *projective* representations of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, which are the same as the linear representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, see also [this Q&A of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/50583).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look!