# Why does one not represent states with equivalence classes in the common formalism?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-states

**Some context:**

Usually, one describes states formally through elements of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (e.g. the n-dimensional vector space of complex numbers with the standard basis and standard scalar product). This way the representation is not unique - two representations $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle=e^{i\gamma}|\psi_1\rangle$ represent the same state.

A unique way of representation is achieved by the equivalence relation $|\psi_1\rangle\sim|\psi_2\rangle:\Leftrightarrow \exists\gamma\in\mathbb{R}:|\psi_1\rangle=e^{i\gamma}|\psi_2\rangle$. Marinescu (978-0-12-383874-2) defines states this way in the first place.

**Question:**

Why does one usually still not calculate with equivalence classes but with elements of $\mathcal{H}$? Also Marinescu abandons the idea of "rays" (meaning equivalence classes) right after introducing them and goes on by using "the state $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$".

Problematic scenario:
Using equivalence classes would come in handy e.g. in the following scenario. Usually in physics, people do identify a mathematical representation with the label of something. In this case, a state is called / labeled $|\psi\rangle$ using the mathematical representation $|\psi\rangle=(1,0)^T$ for example. Since two representations $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle=e^{i\gamma}|\psi_1\rangle$ represent the same state (since measurement statistics don't differ), one would have two different terms/labels for the same, which is not welcomed. If one used equivalence classes, this problem wouldn't exist.

Edit: I quickly want to touch on the fact that I said "states are represented by elements of a Hilbert space" and not "states are elements of a Hilbert space". In my opinion, this doesn't matter for the question, since "identifying a mathematical representation with the label of something" as explained in my "problematic scenario" is exactly what this is. Although I see many books don't see a more general term "state" above the mathematical entity - as a sidenote: is there a reason for this?

Comment: Sometimes people write $|x\rangle$ for an element of a Hilbert space; sometimes they use the same notation for an equivalence class of elements.  Sometimes they use the same notation for two different things in the same sentence and rely on the reader to sort out what's what.  Sometimes people write $2$ to represent a certain integer; sometimes they use the same symbol to represent a certain real number.  Sometimes they use the same notation for both things in the same sentence and rely on the reader to sort out what's what.  Does that also bother you?

Comment: I don't understand the query (again). If you postulate that states are rays and that observables are represented by (hermitian) operators, you have to state what we will measure with what probability. We can postulate that e.g. in a state described by the ray $[\psi]$ the expectation value of an observable, described by $A$, is given as $\langle A\rangle_{[\psi]}:=\langle \psi|A|\psi\rangle$, where $\psi \in [\psi]$ is any (normalized) representative. You need to show that this is indeed well-defined, i.e. does not depend on the representative chosen - and you're done.

Comment: For certain aspects it is indeed important to distinguish the ray from its representatives (see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203944/why-exactly-do-sometimes-universal-covers-and-sometimes-central-extensions-feat)). The reason most intro text books do not distinguish both notions is, as described above, most calculations can be done with a choice of a representative, which eases most of the discussion and computations This is similar to the case $H=L^2(\mathbb R)$, where elements are also equivalence classes, and not functions, but the difference is mostly ignored.

Comment: @WillO Yes indeed.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thank you for your input. What you wrote in your second message is a different point of view on what is given in the accepted answer and solves my confusion! Just to clear up why all this confused me: What you wrote here, is not explained anywhere and is something one has to get used to, if before one has always tried to work with semantics that are "precisely defined". So this "meta information" is what was missing for me. I like to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess part of the confusion is that there are multiple levels of modeling involved. At the very top, you have the actual physical phenomena, which may be complicated and have aspects beyond our knowledge.

Then you narrow that down to only the aspects that are relevant to quantum mechanics: your conceptual model of a quantum state - the physical state. This is the thing that ultimately determines the behavior observed in quantum phenomena and measurement outcomes.

It is an abstraction, and, to quote Edsger W. Dijkstra: "The purpose of abstraction is not to be vague, but to create a new semantic level in which one can be absolutely precise." An abstraction defines conceptually what aspects are relevant (and therefore also what can be ignored or assumed away). So, this abstract state does not necessarily completely describe every aspect of the physical system - but it does completely describe it within the confines of the theoretical model.

Then you have the formal mathematical model of the physical state, a *ray* in projective Hilbert space (the "ray" terminology comes from the concept of projective spaces). But rays are kind of inconvenient to work with, so you represent states with elements of a Hilbert space. Someone more knowledgeable than me will have to explain why exactly that's the case, but I have a feeling that it has to do with the apparatus of linear algebra and calculus being available for use on Hilbert spaces, and also with the fact that this formalism is more readily utilized by computers.

So, now instead of having rays as first class elements of your model, you have equivalence classes "in the background", but you work with the elements of a Hilbert space - and you keep track of the fact that some formally different elements are going to represent the same conceptual physical state (those lying on the same ray / in the same equivalence class). Because of this, you have to be careful about how you manipulate them mathematically (e.g. how you add them, you're careful to normalize things, etc).

Then keeping all that in mind, you use the term "state" somewhat loosely (e.g. you say "state $|\psi\rangle$" instead of "state represented by $|\psi\rangle$", or some such thing), but ultimately, you're really concerned with the physical states.

Comment: In case I use your thought in the paragraph starting with "So, now instead of having" in a sidenote in a thesis - do you want me to cite this answer? I'm asking, because while this thought is implicit included in every quantum mechanics book, it is not quite obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @manuel459 - nah, go ahead. Just rephrase and/or expand on it, among other things, to avoid it being falsely flagged as plagiarism by automated checkers. You know, use it as a starting point, but make the end result an expression of your own understanding, in your own writing style.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how doing calculations with "equivalence class of quantum states" instead of with psi function like it is usually done, would look like - if you know, maybe add some examples into the question. Density matrix induced by single psi function $\rho(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \psi^*(\mathbf r)\psi(\mathbf r')$ has diagonal terms that do not depend on the phase and thus on the representation, but it still has off-diagonal terms that are not unique -they can change if we change to $\psi'(\mathbf r) = e^{i\gamma(\mathbf r)} \psi(\mathbf r)$ with coordinate-dependent $\gamma$.

However, I am not sure about the motivation. What would be the value? Calculations in physics very often use non-unique representations of all things involved - coordinates, physical quantities, even numbers. These are not unique, but refer to some frame of reference, convention, agreed upon definition, or numeral system. Uniqueness of representation of these things is not very important in physics.