Why every projective irreducible representation of $(ISO(2,1)^{\uparrow}=SO(2,1)^{\uparrow}\ltimes \mathbb{R}^3)$ is equivalent?
Why every projective irreducible representation of the connected poincare group $(ISO(2,1)^{\uparrow}=SO(2,1)^{\uparrow}\ltimes \mathbb{R}^3)$ is equivalent to a projective irreducible representation of its double cover $(SL(2,\mathbb{R})\ltimes \mathfrak{sl}_{Ad}(2,\mathbb{R}))$? where $Ad:SL(2,\mathbb{R})\to \mathfrak{sl}_{Ad}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the adjoint representation. I have also this question that why very projective irreducible representation of the connected Lie group is equivalent to an exact irreducible representation of its universal cover. Are these statements theorems? Unfortunately I don't understand the language of "The quantum theory of fields" book by S. Weinberg and it's a little bit hard to me. Is there a good reference for that?

See my Q&A at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/50583, the name of the theorem in case no central extensions occur is Bargmann's theorem.

@ACuriousMind Thank you very much. you proved in the link that projective representations of a Lie group are in bijection to linear representations of  its central extensions. I have a question: Let $G$ be a Lie group (we know that $\pi_1 (G)$ is abelian) and $\hat{G}$ be a cover group for $G$ which is not necessary universal (like the double cover group of $ISO(2,1)^{\uparrow}$ I mentioned avobe which is not universal).  Since $\hat{G}$ is not necessary universal, it has projective representation.

On the other hand, $\hat{G}$ is the central extension of $G$ by $\pi_1 (G)$ and by what you said, the projective representations of $G$ are in bijection to linear representations of $\hat{G}$. But $\hat{G}$ has projective ones as well. What about them? Are projective representations of $G$  in bijection to projective representations of $\hat{G}$ as well?

@ACuriousMind Why do we work on double cover instead of universal cover in the poincae case?

We don't need the projective representations of $\hat{G}$ in this process?
